# How to exit the black terminal screen?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I was normally working on Ubuntu 16.04. I pressed some random keys and a black full screen appeared asking me to login and submit my password. After doing so I have only a black full screen terminal like that of UNIX/DOS without GUI.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F#</kbd>

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the normal interface.

Comment: Yes. I had pressed ctrl+alt+f6.

Comment: On RHEL, I used ctrl + alt + f2.

Answer (score 1):

Juste type ctrl-alt-F1 to F6 to switch between tty's, try ctrl-alt-F2 as it is where your graphic term should be defaulted (F1 is the login screen, F3 to F6 are text term - may vary upon distro, try for yourself;).

Comment: OP uses 16.04. There F1-F6 are consoles and F7 is the GUI. They have changed it in 17.04 to what you say.

Comment: On RHEL, I used ctrl + alt + f2

Answer (score 1):

You can go back to gui-mode by pressing:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> keys.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal use:

```
sudo chvt 7
```